# How to make an upload from local filesystem?

Tags: django, upload, photo

I'm playing around with swfupload but I think it's a bit hard to integrate it in the django admin of a photo app of mine. So now I'm looking for an upload tool that opens the local filesystem in the browser an let you select files to be uploaded. I've seen this quite often in such online photo-developing-services...any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with local filesytem? client or server ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I am missing something... Why not using django FileField ?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Comment: because it sucks if you want to upload 100 files and you have to upload them manually and you have to wait for each file indiviudally to be uploaded.

Comment: oh ok! I get it now, once a time I had a similar problem having to upload lots of files. What I did was to upload a zip file, and then unzip in the server, but not sure if that meets your requirements.